# Como recorrer un datagridview y sumar cuando coincida un codigo? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito recorrer una columna de mi DataGridView llamada "codigo" cuando inserte uno en el textbox , si lo encuentra simplemente que la columna llamada "Capturado" de la misma fila aumente en 1, de lo contrario que no haga nada, es como una caja de supermercado, estoy verificando un pedido con un lector de codigos de barras

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar con alguna idea de como hacerlo (no necesito todo el codigo) se lo agradeceria mucho, soy muy nuevo con esto , gracias de antemano

[image: Captura del DataGridView que estoy usando]

Edit 18/12/2018

Muchas gracias , modifique un codigo que me comentaron abajo, al final funciono asi:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            String a = null;
            a = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells[0].Value);
            if (a == txtCodigo.Text)
            {
                int n = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[3].Value);
                n = n + 1;
                fila.Cells[3].Value = n;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola @DemarSeveriano, bienvenio a SOes. ¿Podrías poner lo que has intentado e indicar dónde te falla? Hace falta que nos pongas código para ver lo que estás haciendo. Puedes leer [ask] para ver como mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias probar esto:

```
foreach(GridViewRow fila in TuDataGridView.Rows){
  if(fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == TextBox.Text)
  {
    fila.Cells[3].Value = 1;
  }
}
```

No estaria al tanto de que si los tipos de datos de la expresion del IF estan bien, pero con esto podrias guiarte un poco y vamos arregando la respuesta hasta dar con la solucion.
De todas formas si piensas manejar todos los datos como string, la mejor forma de comprararlos seria de la siguente

```
if(fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(TextBox.Text) == 0)
```

Comment: Disculpa, me marca el error 

"System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get devolvió null."

y la segunda opcion de if me dice que no puede usar el comparador == en un bool , te enseño capturas , de antemano gracias por la ayuda 

[https://i.imgur.com/gIykJbr.png]

Comment: Listo amigo, muchas gracias, modifique un poco el codigo por que me salian algunos errores, en el update enseño como quedo, gracias de nuevo

Comment: Hola, estaba viendo la captura, entonces pudiste solucionar el problema ?

Comment: SI muchas gracias, no se bien que cual era el problema pero ocupe unas variables auxiliares para no modificar directamente sobre el gridview por que hacia raro y cambie la conversion a string por que tambien daba algunos errores, ahora ya funciona justo como queria, muchas gracias, edite la pregunta arriba para que puedas ver como quedo

Answer (score 1):

Para localizar una row en el grid no necesita recorrerlo puede usar linq, con una simple query acceder a la row

```
var row = (from item in DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
             where item.Cells["Codigo"].Value.ToString() == txtCodigo.Text
           select item).FirstOrDefault();

if(row != null){
   var cellCapturado = row.Cells["Capturado"];
   cellCapturado.Value = Convert.ToInt32(cellCapturado.Value) + 1;
}
```

imagine queria ir sumando si se realizaban mas de una lectura del mismo codigo

Tambien la query linq se podria haber realizado de la siguiente forma

```
var row = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                       .FirstOrDefault(item=> item.Cells["Codigo"].Value == txtCodigo.Text);
```

es otro forma usando los metodos de extension

Comment: use el codigo como lo muestras y me marcas y me marca este error:

[https://i.imgur.com/mXRyJtj.png] 

ademas de que muestra que la variable item no existe (no se de que tipo es para crearla, disculpa )

Comment: Resolvi el problema que marcaba utilizando value.ToString, pero aun me marca que la variable item no existe, me podrias ayudar con la forma de declararla por favor?

Comment: edite el codigo, igual por lo que veo lo resolviste con un foreach en lugar de linq